# Envoy configuration and documentation

Tags: envoyproxy

I am a newbie in envoy. with my learning I was able to build very simple envoy gateway. I would now like to deep dive in the configurations and tuning the settings of envoy. But the Envoy documentation seems to be little difficult for me to understand. Could anybody help me understanding how to read, understand and apply the documentation concepts to build and modify the settings in envoy config yaml file. As an example say I want to change the memory settings of my Envoy config how to do that

Thanks
Anant

Answer (score 1):

I would start by going through the free tutorials here: https://academy.tetrate.io/courses/envoy-fundamentals

Also, I would take a peek at the configuration best practices here: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.22.0/configuration/best_practices/best_practices and that covers a production envoy configuration.

Unfortunately the documentation is rather hard to follow and requires a lot of trial and error.. hopefully those two resources will get you started.